# Rust: How to cast from a signed integer type to a larger signed integer type *without* sign extension

Tags: casting, rust

Suppose we have an `i8` which we want to cast to an `i16` *without* sign extension.

We can't do us a simple `as` cast, as this will sign extend.

```
println!("{:b}", -128i8); // 10000000 <- we want this zero-extended in an i16.
println!("{:b}", -128i8 as i16);  // 1111111110000000 sign extended :(
```

We cannot transmute, because the types are of different size:

```
println!("{:b}", unsafe {mem::transmute::<_, i16>(128i8)});
// ^ error[E0512]: cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types :(
```

The best I've come up with is the following convoluted casting chain:

```
println!("{:b}", -128i8 as u8 as u16 as i16); // 10000000 :), but :( because convoluted.
```

The intermediate cast to `u8` means that casting up to a `u16` will zero-extend instead of sign extend, then casting from `u16` to `i16` is fine, as the types are the same size and no extension is required.

But there must be a better way? Is there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keeping in mind that for this case (printing the number's bits) you can just do the unsigned conversion.

However in general Rust doesn't really like doing implicit conversions, but you can always write

```rust
let n : i8 = -128;
let m : i32 = n as u8 as i32;
```

You pretty much can't get better than this in general, as double casting is common in fields like changing pointer's types. Also consider not using unsafe when the operation you are doing can be done safely without downsides (aside from maybe a slight code smell).

Comment: Since `u8 -> i32` is a lossless conversion you could also write `let m: i32 = (n as u8).into();` or `let m = i32::from(n as u8);`